# How to cluster images of each person in a dataset?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a directory which contains many images of different faces which are captured by a webcam. 
Every person's face is captured 10-20 times and over a period of time(eg:personA images: img_01,img02,img19,img20; personB images: img_03,img13,img14 etc.,)

I want to cluster all the images of each person and group them as one so that I have **as many clusters as the number of persons.**(eg: If there are 10 persons faces and 50 images in directory then I should get 10 clusters or count as 10). What method can I follow to group the same person's images. I am working on Python. Please assist me in this.

This is how my folder looks like ->click 1 to view screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIf6F.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a technique called **k-means**. This will take a dataset and cluster it into $k$ different clusters. You can set $k$ to 10 if you know you have 10 people.

However, you will need to consider that an image is very high dimensional. You will need to find a way to reduce this set through feature extraction. This can be done a few different ways. If you are using openCV then you can directly get the distances for the person nose and eyes, and all that. Those can be good identifier metrics. Otherwise, I would suggest you build a type of autoencoder, then use the compressed set as the features to your k-means algorithm.

---

## Detect facial features

OpenCV has many functions which can do a whole load of facial detection stuff. I would recommend using the following techniques presented in [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/10/detect-eyes-nose-lips-jaw-dlib-opencv-python/). This will detect the nose, eyes and face shape. From these points you can then calculate some metrics. I would suggest to use a few different ratios

1. distance between eyes : distance from nose to eyes.
2. distance between eye corners : distance between mouth corners

You can keep getting creative and get more metrics.

## Getting the dataset

Then you will build a dataset where the rows are each individual picture. Then each column will represent a feature. This will be these ratios that you compute using your images.

## Applying k-means to the dataset

Then you can use the sklearn packages for k-means which has an example code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: could you please elaborate about auto encoder & compressed set as the features

Comment: What does your data currently look like? Just pictures?

Comment: I have added link of the screenshot of my data

Comment: I made an edit adding more information.